# 2 different Google Cloud SQL instances down twice in the past week

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm hoping you have some idea as to what this issue is.

I've had a Google Cloud SQL instance runnning for only a few days and then it outright dies. I can't connect to it from Terminal, my website can't connect to it either and the only solution is to back it up and make a new instance.

I will keep the instance alive to troubleshoot but this is becoming a real problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Like I said I can't connect to the instance so I can only get information from my Developers console.

Comment: Are you allowing access from 0.0.0.0/0 or only some specific IPs? Could you confirm that the IP you are trying to access from is authorized? Also, which is the activation policy for those instances (Always on or on demand) ?

Comment: Please email us at cloud-sql@google.com with all details: 1) instance name, 2) the time window in which things are working, 3) the time window in which they aren't working, 4) the frequency of the issue, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adrián Specific IPs (one being the Static IP of my server). Yes its authorized (I checked quite a few times). I've tried both but this time it was always on.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Will do. Thanks for the message!